# Найти натуральный степень тройки

Tags: javascript

Помогите написать код который проверяет на то что число является ли натуральной степенью тройки. Например, число 27 — это третья степень: 3^3, а 81 — это четвёртая: 3^4.

Comment: Добавьте то, что Вы сделали, чтобы решить Вашу задачу, кроме прошения о помощи. Минус мой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через рекурсию

```js
const isPowerOfThree = (num) => {
    const findPowerOfThree = (num) =>{
        if(num%3 !== 0 || num <= 1) return 0;        
        return 1 + findPowerOfThree(num/3);
    }
    return 3**findPowerOfThree(num) === num;
}
console.log(isPowerOfThree(81)) // true 3^4
```